# Randomly printing gets very slow - Windows Update suspect n° 1

Tags: drivers, printer, windows-update

In our small office LAN, we use a Kiocera Mita KM-165FX for printing, configured as a network printer.
Every now and again (may happen every couple months) ALL the computers (Windows 7 e Windows 8) will be very slow at printing. The only why to fix this is to uninstall the printer from Windows and reinstall (takes time because multiple drivers exist).

I suspect this could be due to Windows update, choosing a newer (but buggier) driver.

What would you try to fix this?

Comment: how many computers are on the lan? is it a domain?

Comment: 3 workstations + a server. Workstations are not part of the domain. The printer is connected through a cable to the LAN, not to the server, so the workstations will print directly to it, bypassing the server